# How extract RabbitMQ management plugin graphs?

Tags: plot, rabbitmq

Is there any way that I can extract graphs in RabbiMQ management plugin?
Right clicking on the graph gives me a blank container and screen-shot quality is not good enough.

I saw the java plugin tests mentioned [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/17/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-1/), but I don't have enough experience to run it based on my needs.
Is there any other way to extract those graph(or even customized graphs like java plugin) in high quality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. 
but you have two ways:

1. the stats are bases on [these API(s)](https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_6/priv/www/api/index.html), you can build your own graphs.
2. you can use some monitoring system as zabbix or others that support RMQ and get the graphs form there

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I take a look at Zabbix, it seems Zabbix allow direct access to graph data on database where I can use them to draw my charts, am I right? and is there any tutorial on how to use API to create stats? I have to run the API command in a loop while queue is active and save them for later use, right?